# Sinch Android Push Notification Failed

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

Have any of you guys seen this issue before ?

I am facing this right now repeatedly.

> 08-16 22:30:26.155 6238-6911/com.abc W/sinch-android-rtc: push: api request to send 
>   push notifications failed:Error(code: 4000, domain: api, message: PushFailed (20054117), 
>   data: {serverCode: 20054117, serverMessage: PushFailed})

Using sinch-android-rtc (3.9.8).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This happen when you try and send a push after calling unregisterPushData

Comment: Hi @cjensen, I am getting same issue with latest iOS SDK (4.2.3-075154b). Any ideas how to fix this ? Looking forward hearing from you soon. Thanks